# How to check Computer system information from web server

Tags: c#, system-information

I am working on a program that i want to gather system information in order to determine if the computer is compatible with software. I would like to add the program to a website for visitors to check their machine. so far it had been uploaded to a web server. but instead of checking the users machine, it only checks the web server. Am i missing like a connect function or something to connect to the user machine, like possibly to connect to localhost or something of the sort. Any advice or help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you show some code or explain what type of system requirements you're trying to check?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that unless you have the client computer install your application.

Comment: so theres no way to establish a connection for the script to execute ?

Answer (score 1):

What sort of information are you looking to obtain from the client machine?

You can check the operating system client-side in Javascript:

http://www.programmersheaven.com/mb/java-script/215704/215704/how-to-retrieve-clients-system-info/

Unfortunately you can't check things like RAM, hard disk space without running on the client machine, so your installation package would need to verify these requirements.