# how to execute a web server app on a client machine

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have some code that should do a system check to see if a machine is compatible with software. its uploaded to a web server. how can I get it to be run on a client machine if some one tries to do the system check on our website?

the code works as it should but I am not sure how to get it running on the website. Thanks for any help given.

its a scenario where You visit on a website, and want to know if your computer can run their software. You should be able to click a button which activates the check and displays the results. my code is in c#.

Comment: is there a web service that could possibly be used.

Comment: how are you doing it currently if you say it works it should work just the same on the client machine which means if it's a web service.. for example.. just consume that webservice in the client application..

Comment: You want the website to check a machine to see what the machine has installed on it and what spec the machien is? Don't think this is possible with a web app. Is the software web based or windows based?

Comment: well I think there is missing some type of connection method for it to execute on the client machine @DJKRAZE

Comment: it should check some of the system specifications like os, ram, disk drive , browsers, @Burt

Comment: Have you looked at Silverlight Out Of Browser? You should be able to then access the typical items. Just a thought and might not work very well based on already developed code.

Comment: @Brad no , if there's a link you could share to read thanks

Comment: @chloe here is some general information. Not 100% sure if possbile but it seems possbile - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd550721(v=VS.95).aspx

Comment: Is the a repeat of your early question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8680235/how-to-check-computer-system-information-from-web-server

Answer (score 0):

You might have to develop a .Net ActiveX component and invoke it from the Javascript. But this will require the client machine to have .Net framework installed. Also you would have to set code access security on the client machine.

The below article explains how to develop .Net ActiveX

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/CreateActiveXDotNet.aspx

Comment: Yeah. For changing your C# code to .Net ActiveX, you need to add few attributes. Follow the link to understand better.

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways in which you can find certain configurations in a web app. For Example if you want to find the browser version you can use the windows.Navigtor.userAgent property in javascript to find the browser version etc..

The above being the easy part now if you want to know the clients Total physical memory and sort of things you would need explicit permissions of the client machine and once you have them you can get few of the system properties using the [ManagementObjectSearcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementobjectsearcher.aspx) class and [ManagementObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementobject.aspx) in .NET.

Answer (score 0):

What are you checking? If it's very simple, like browser version, etc, you can use the web app. Otherwise, this sounds like a candidate for [ClickOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d.aspx) deployment.

Comment: I was wondering if I am missing some function like a server listening for a connection or something of that nature ? similar to this http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-simple-threaded-tcp-server maybe ?

Comment: Don't think so. You can check OS and browser from the server variables. However, when you cross into disk and ram, that's not accessible through the browser. You need a local app to do this.ClickOnce will give you this. You would need to port your app to a winform app. Should REALLY be easy.

Comment: also you mean changing the app to a windows form app in visual studio instead of working like a webpage correct?

Comment: Yes. Question for you: Why don't you do the requirements check when initially loading the software?

Comment: uhm well that wasn't really in the requirements, I think that will be in the installer but that is not my task ....